# bash if [ -n "$output of a variable" ]

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep

```
line=$(grep "# rvm line" ~/.bashrc)

if [ ! -n "$line" ]; then
  echo "found"
else
  echo "not found"
fi
```

What's wrong with my quotes in the first line?

EDIT: The problem is `set -o errexit`, which I use in my script. I suppose `-n` is treated as an error, exiting the following processes. How can I overcome this, keeping the error check? (Alternatives to -n could work too).

Comment: wrong kind of red-hue? Change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x` or use `set -vx` and examine the output...

Comment: you are using `-n` wrongly, means True if string is not empty and then you negate that using `!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't plan to use `$line` for anything else than testing if it's empty or not, then you might as well do this:

```
if grep -q '# rvm line' ~/.bashrc; then
  echo "found"
else
  echo "not found"
fi
```

Comment: That's perfect. It's shorter and doesn't exit the script when used with `set -o errexit`

Answer (score 1):

**Nothing**

Nothing is apparently wrong with the quotes? Are you not getting expected result ?

ok,your if condition is wrong - if it was intended to check that something was returned by the grep statement. I will leave that as a clue for yourself to figure out. Goodluck

Comment: hmm.. you're right. It's working by itself, but when it's within my script, it just locks.